# Iterator Implementation - (Linked List Queue)

Tags: c++, eclipse, data-structures, queue

I am implementing an iterator for a Queue data type, but the iterator is being initialized as a const inside of the class implementation for some reason. I cannot figure out why the constructor is causing the iterator to return itself as a const.

Any feedback as to what the intricasies of the C++ language that may be causing my problem could be, would be very helpful.

The Error I am receiving from Eclipse which seems to be coming from my begin() method is:

```
../src/linked_queue.hpp:315:35: error: invalid conversion from 
    'const ics::LinkedQueue<int>*' to 'ics::LinkedQueue<int>*' [-fpermissive]
```

Interface:

```
#ifndef LINKED_QUEUE_HPP_
#define LINKED_QUEUE_HPP_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include "ics_exceptions.hpp"


namespace ics {


template<class T> class LinkedQueue {
  public:
    //Destructor/Constructors
    ~LinkedQueue();

    LinkedQueue          ();
    LinkedQueue          (const LinkedQueue<T>& to_copy);
    explicit LinkedQueue (const std::initializer_list<T>& il);


    template <class Iterable>
    explicit LinkedQueue (const Iterable& i);


    //Queries
    bool empty      () const;
    int  size       () const;
    T&   peek       () const;
    std::string str () const; //supplies useful debugging information; contrast to operator <<


    //Commands
    int  enqueue (const T& element);
    T    dequeue ();
    void clear   ();

    template <class Iterable>
    int enqueue_all (const Iterable& i);


    //Operators
    LinkedQueue<T>& operator = (const LinkedQueue<T>& rhs);
    bool operator == (const LinkedQueue<T>& rhs) const;
    bool operator != (const LinkedQueue<T>& rhs) const;

    template<class T2>
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& outs, const LinkedQueue<T2>& q);



  private:
    class LN;

  public:
    class Iterator {
      public:

        ~Iterator();
        T           erase();
        std::string str  () const;
        LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator& operator ++ ();
        LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator  operator ++ (int);
        bool operator == (const LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator& rhs) const;
        bool operator != (const LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator& rhs) const;
        T& operator *  () const;
        T* operator -> () const;
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& outs, const LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator& i) {
          outs << i.str(); 
          return outs;
        }
        friend Iterator LinkedQueue<T>::begin () const;
        friend Iterator LinkedQueue<T>::end   () const;

      private:

        LN*             prev = nullptr;  
        LN*             current;         
        LinkedQueue<T>* ref_queue;
        int             expected_mod_count;
        bool            can_erase = true;

        Iterator(LinkedQueue<T>* iterate_over, LN* initial);
    };


    Iterator begin () const;
    Iterator end   () const;


  private:
    class LN {
      public:
        LN ()                      {}
        LN (const LN& ln)          : value(ln.value), next(ln.next){}
        LN (T v,  LN* n = nullptr) : value(v), next(n){}

        T   value;
        LN* next = nullptr;
    };


    LN* front     =  nullptr;
    LN* rear      =  nullptr;
    int used      =  0;            //Cache for number of values in linked list
    int mod_count =  0;            //For sensing any concurrent modifications

    //Helper methods
    void delete_list(LN*& front);
};
```

Implementation (I've included only a section of my Iterator code):

```
template<class T>
auto LinkedQueue<T>::begin () const -> LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator {
    return Iterator(this, this->front);
}

template<class T>
auto LinkedQueue<T>::end () const -> LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator {
    // return Iterator(this, this->rear);
}

template<class T>
LinkedQueue<T>::Iterator::Iterator(LinkedQueue<T>* iterate_over, LN* initial) {
    ref_queue = iterate_over;
    expected_mod_count = iterate_over->mod_count;
    current = initial;
}
```

Comment: `Iterator begin () const;` is marked as `const`, hence the `this` used in the function is `const` as well. So in turn, the compiler gives the error that it cannot convert from a const to non-const.

Comment: Understandable. But I'm taking this for a class, and I am supposed to implement the function this way, so is there any way to implement the Iterator / begin function correctly, so that I can pass a reference to itself to the Iterator?

Comment: You could add `const` to the constructor signature `Iterator(LinkedQueue<T> const* iterate_over, LN* initial);` and the member const as well `LinkedQueue<T> const* ref_queue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `Iterator begin () const;` is marked as `const`, hence the `this` used in the function is `const` as well. So in turn, the compiler gives the error that it cannot convert from a const to non-const.

Given that the function signatures are fixed in this case, to resolve the error, added `const` will help solve the issue.

You could add `const` to the constructor signature

```
Iterator(LinkedQueue<T> const* iterate_over, LN* initial);
```

And make the member `const` as well

```
LinkedQueue<T> const* ref_queue;
```

Adding the `const` where required to ensure that members and functions remain `const` as required is known as [being `const` correct](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const).